# URL of calendar running on mac server (to subscribe in google calendar)

Tags: calendar, osx-server, google-calendar

I am running OS 10.8 server on a mac mini. I have the calenddar service enabled and created an extra user for calendars.

I have no problem subscribing to those calendars by creating an OSX server account on other macs using the "Mail, Contacts & Calendars" setting in system preferences.

Is it possible to subscribe to such a calendar online, using google calendar? Google Calendar has an option to "add via URL" (right click on further calendars at the bottom left) -- how can I figure out what the URL of my calendar is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribing to a Calendar and accessing a Calendar account are two very different things. As you mentioned above, you can *access* this calendar from a Mac by visiting "Mail, Contacts & Calendars". However, to *subscribe to* a calendar there is a slightly more involved process.

First, go to your primary Mac that you use this account from. Open the **Calendar** or **iCal** app. Locate the calendar you'd like to access from Google from the Calendars sidebar. Right-click this calendar and select **Publish...** You can now enter a website U RL, user ID and password, choose your settings and click "Publish" to publish your calendar.

Take the URL that it published to and you can now subscribe to this published calendar in Google Calendar (via *add via URL*).

Keep in mind... when you publish a calendar, it essentially sits on a Web Server. That means you will need to have a web hosting provider to publish to. If you do not, you can always start the Web Service on your OS X Server and publish to that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this! Could you also give a few pointers for starting a webservice? -- my server has an URL from dyndns. Would that be sufficient for the domain name? This is what I currently do and I get a The server responded with “502” error. If I wanted to store the calendar at some other place on the server, where would I specify that (f.ex. `https://server.com/mycalfiles`)?

Comment: Sorry for the very late response. Took a bit of a hiatus from Ask Different. I've not used dyndns. I typically do Static IP with a FQDN. A 502 error typically deals with a routing issue through an internet Gateway. Dyndns could potentially be the issue.

Comment: In OS X Server, you can start the "Web" service, and designate a physical folder on the server that acts as the location for files on that website. You can also assign your login credentials, etc. based on your Open Directory accounts. Then you will want to setup a web domain or subdomain, setup your A Records, DNS, etc etc.  You might check out [this site](http://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/10.8) for more assistance, or post a question on [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) to get better help on the DNS/Networking side of things.

Comment: I must backtrack some of my previous comments, and I sincerely apologize. It has been some time since I have done this and am actually working on a similar issue myself right now. It is the WebDAV service you have to enable (via File Sharing in OS X Server), not Web Service. However I am actually having issues with metadata with OS X 10.8 Server which I didn't have years ago. Sigh. I'll be posting an article and probably give a bounty to it so hopefully we'll get our answer!